# method that accepts a generic class as argument in c#

Tags: c#, generics

In my project I have a generic class, which is used to store data and pass to another function:

```
public class SqlCommandParameter<T>
{
    public string ParameterName { get;private set; }
    public SqlDbType SqlDbType { get; private set; }
    public T SqlDbValue { get; private set; }

    public SqlCommandParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType, T sqlDbValue)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        SqlDbType = sqlDbType;
        SqlDbValue = sqlDbValue;
    }
}
```

but when I tried to pass instances of this to another function, it gives the error: **Cannot resolve T**. Here is my method declaration:

```
 public Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(int? id, string commandTextQuery, CommandType commandType,params SqlCommandParameter<T>[] parameters )
    { ... }
```

Since the number or values to the stored procedure is different, I'm passing it as `params`. How can I pass the generic class to the function in the proper way? Can anyone suggest a way to do this without error?

Comment: `GetDataAsync<T>` - you need to make the method generic unless you specify a type for T in the method signature

Comment: (Or unless it's a method in a generic class.)

Comment: Adding that `T` Worked
Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @sony I don't think `GetDataAsync<T>` is the answer you are looking for - it will limit set of acceptable parameters to just single type per call (unless it is exactly what you want).

Comment: then you can use dynamic to send params `GetDataAsync(id,ctq, ct, new SqlCommandParameters<dynamic>(...),new SqlCommandParameters<dynamic>(...));`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not a generic expert, but `GetDataAsync<T>` is exactly what I want

Comment: @sony So all of the provided command parameters will always have the same generic argument?  None of them will vary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `GetDataAsync()` a generic method, `GetDataAsync<T>()` but *all* parameters will be limited to whatever `T` happens to be when you call the method:

```
GetDataAsync(..., new SqlCommandParameter<int>(), new SqlCommandParameter<int>());
```

will work, but

```
GetDataAsync(..., new SqlCommandParameter<int>(), new SqlCommandParameter<string>());
```

will not. One option would be to derive your generic `SqlCommandParameter<T>` from a non-generic `SqlCommandParameter` and pass in the non-generic to a non-generic `GetDataAsync()`:

```
public abstract class SqlCommandParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
    public SqlDbType SqlDbType { get; private set; }

    protected SqlCommandParameters(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        SqlDbType = sqlDbType;
    }
}

public class SqlCommandParameter<T>: SqlCommandParameter
{
    public T SqlDbValue { get; private set; }

    public SqlCommandParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType, T sqlDbValue): base(parameterName, sqlDbType)
    {
        SqlDbValue = sqlDbValue;
    }
}
```

With the above, this call below will work:

```
GetDataAsync(..., new SqlCommandParameter<int>(), new SqlCommandParameter<string>());
```

if the signature of the method is

```
public Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(
    int? id,
    string commandTextQuery,
    CommandType commandType,
    params SqlCommandParameter[] parameters )  { ... }
```

Another solution is to create a container for your generic parameters and pass in that container to the method *without* `params` because you will be passing in just that one collection.